# Simultaneous form validation with HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to validate data using Javascript and the form validation from HTML5 at the same time? Currently when I click my submit button, the HTML5 validation runs first, then once that is fixed, the Javascript then executes.

As this is part of a school assignment, I cannot use any outside libraries including Jquery, and I must use both forms of validation.

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: you might wanna read this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: Unclear what you are even asking. What would “running them at the same time” even entail? Or, what is the actual _result_ you are trying to get here? If you want our help with this, then you really need to ask a better question. So please start by reading [ask].

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "at the same" time? One aspect of JS is that it reponds to events from the UI so it would naturally follow that it would execute after the HTML validation. If you posted your code and went into a bit more detail we could better understand.

Answer (score -4):

if not created custon submit function ?

need custom function

```
function submit_a() {
    var a = $("input[name=form_1_text]").val();
    var b = $("input[name=form_2_text]").val();
    if (a !== ''
        or null) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: _"As this is part of a school assignment, I cannot use any outside libraries **including Jquery**, and I must use both forms of validation"_ - READ the question!

Comment: How does this even attempt to answer the question?

Comment: at least update jquery only sample: getElementByname().value() like try;   also How do you do it without writing a function?